# Remove Haptic Feedback from UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uipickerview, haptic-feedback

I know how to add haptic feedback to elements in my Swift app, but how can I remove the native haptic feedback that comes with the UIPickerView?

Comment: I don't think you can't, it's the kind of things Apple doesn't allow.